# Proof explanation of why every group of prime order is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation

Proposition: Let $G$ be a group of prime order $p$. Let $a$ be any element of $G$ other than the identity. Then $G$ is the cyclic group $\langle a \rangle$ generated by $a$.

Common proof: 
$a$ was chosen so that $|a| >1$. As $a$ is in $G$, the order of $a$ divides the order of $G$, which is a prime integer $p$. Thus, the order of $a$ is $p$. Thus, $|\langle a \rangle |=p$. **Since $G$ has order $p$, $G = \langle a \rangle$**.

My question relates to the bold line. It seems to me that in order to make this conclusion, we need something that says any two groups of the same order with a common element are equivalent. I am not aware of any theorems that state this, and I was wondering if this is true. If it's not, what allows us to make the statement that since $G$ and $\langle a \rangle$ have the same order, $G = \langle a \rangle$?

Comment: $\langle a \rangle$ has $p$ elements and is a subset of $G$ (also with $p$ elements), so they must be equal.  This is the definition (essentially) of $a$ generating $G$.

Comment: Two groups of equal order and an common element (what do you think that means) don't need to be equivalent.  But $\langle a \rangle $ and G don't have one element in common.  They have *all* elements in common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that every element in $\langle a \rangle$ is in $G$, by closure. So since they have the same number of distinct elements, they are the same group.